# Detect whether the mouse is touching the ground or if it is in the air

Tags: c#, .net, mouse

My sister and me are writing a program to help people, that suffer from tremor (trembling in hands).

The program recognizes if the mouse cursor is getting slower and then makes the cursor easier controllable and slower to make using a mouse with trembling hands easier.

The program works so far and there is only one problem: if the user lifts the mouse to another position, the speed is 0 for a short span of time. The program assumes that the cursor has to be slowed down, but this should not happen.

Is there any way to detect whether the mouse is touching the mouse pad/ground?

We are programming in C#.

Comment: Good question, but I don't think it is possible unfortunately

Comment: We tried recognize the movement of the user lifting the mouse in the air by the speed the mouse cursor has. If a person is trembling, the speed of the mouse cursor well almost never be 0. If the mouse is in the air, the speed should be 0. Unfortunately this did not work very well....

Comment: An idea: I assume that if the mouse stops intentionally, it has slowed down first. While if it's up in the air, the stop would be more abrupt. Maybe try to detect that? If you already have an algorithm for that, it might only be a matter of calibrating/refining it. I'd advise that you capture a mouse speed stream in various situations and make a graph out of it. It'll make the characteristics around the behavior you want to detect more obvious.

Comment: Good ideas, but this was also our first guess. We made a graph just like you said but it showed that speed values did not stop that abrupt. We assume that this happens because the user is still moving in a certain direction and the mouse is only half-way in the air. Or maybe the user also gets slower when reaching the and of the mousepad.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to characterize what the mouse data loss like in this case,  and then have your program ignore movement that matches.

For  example, is the movement only exactly zero when the mouse is lifted our not being moved?  If so,  ignore movement under a low threshold.

Comment: We tried that, but it did not work that well. And before we used more time for that, we wanted to ask you guys because you know so much and there might be an easier option

Comment: The results were very inconsitent, sometimes the recognition worked but we were not abled to really make it work. We also tried in the most simple way (measuring how long the speed had been close to zero). Maybe an more complex algorithm could help...